# Sort printed photo dimensions

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a single MySQL field that holds printed photo sizes as text such as:
4x6, 5x7, 8x10, 16x20, 20x24 etc

I need list these in a drop down box using PHP but in dimensional order (as listed above).  If I sorted by alpha I would get:
16x20, 20x24, 4x6, 5x7, 8x10.

I'm guessing I need to do something with the position of the "x".  It will always be in position 2 or position 3 but not sure how to sort this out.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly, but...

```
ORDER BY
   CAST(SUBSTR(yourfield, 0, LOCATE('x', yourfield)) AS int),
   CAST(SUBSTR(yourfield FROM (LOCATE('x', yourfield) + 1)) AS int)
```

not tested, might be wrong, but should do the trick. If this is something that will be done frequently, I'd suggest storing the two sizes in seperate INT fields and concat/stringify them as needed when it comes to display time.

Comment: This returned error:  $query="SELECT * FROM sizes ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(size, 0, LOCATE('x', size)) AS int), CAST(SUBSTR(size FROM (LOCATE('x', size) + 1)) AS int)";